# Illegal parameter number in definition of in a macro that doesn't have

Tags: tables, macros

In the next code, I use a macro without parameter, that doesn't complain until I use multicolumn in it.

> l.40  \TabTikzMark*{3}
>                       \hline
>   ? ^C! Interruption.
>   \@preamble ...begin \ignorespaces \@sharp \unskip 
>                                                     \relax \d@llarend \hfil > \h...
>
> l.40  \TabTikzMark*{3}
>                       \hline

The goal is to have the tikzmarks on each corners of each boxes of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array,xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{TabTikzCount}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\TabTikzMark}{sm}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]\noalign{\setcounter{TabTikzCount}{1}}%
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]%
        }{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\Row}[1]{%
%\def\MyRow{\tikzmark{\Alph{TabTikzCount}0}}%
\def\MyRow{\multicolumn{1}{@{c@{}}}\begingroup\tikzmark{\Alph{TabTikzCount}0}}%
\foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n-1)] in {2,...,#1} {%
\let\tikzmark\relax%
%\xdef\MyRow{\MyRow\strut\hfill\tikzmark{\Alph{TabTikzCount}\m}}%
\xdef\MyRow{\MyRow\strut\hfill\tikzmark{\Alph{TabTikzCount}\m}%
\endgroup&\multicolumn{1}{@{c@{}}}\begingroup}%
}%
\MyRow\hfill\tikzmark{\Alph{TabTikzCount}#1}\endgroup%
\stepcounter{TabTikzCount}}

\begin{document}

essai

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\TabTikzMark*{3}\hline
a&z&a\TabTikzMark{3}\hline
a&z&a\TabTikzMark{3}\hline
\end{tabular}

essai

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[->] (pic cs:A0) -- (pic cs:C3) ;

\end{document}
```

**Edit :** It can be done with `lualatex`, but there is a strange shift in `tikzmark`s. I post a new question on that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array,xparse,luacode}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{TabTikzCount}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\TabTikzMark}{sm}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]\noalign{\setcounter{TabTikzCount}{1}}%
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]%
        }{%
        \\[-\ht\@arstrutbox]
        \Row{3}
        \\[-\dp\@arstrutbox]}}
\makeatother

\begin{luacode}
function row (s)
    a = "\\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\\tikzmark{\\Alph{TabTikzCount}0}"
    for i = 1,s-1
    do
    a=a.."\\strut\\hfill\\tikzmark{\\Alph{TabTikzCount}"..i.."}}&\\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{"
    end
    a=a.."\\strut\\hfill\\tikzmark{\\Alph{TabTikzCount}"..s.."}}"
    tex.print (a)
    print (a)
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\Row}[1]{%
\directlua{row(#1)}
\stepcounter{TabTikzCount}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\TabTikzMark*{4}\hline
a&z&a&d\TabTikzMark{4}\hline
a&z&a&d\TabTikzMark{4}\hline
\end{tabular}

\foreach \j in {A,B,C} {%
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} {%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]
        \node at (pic cs:\j\i) {\tiny \j\i} ;
}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzmark` inside `\xdef` doesn’t seem like a good idea

Comment: It seems to work thanks to \relax, the problem comes with the multicolums ans the begin and end groups. I've left the comented lines without the multicolums stuff.

Comment: You cannot hope that `\multicolumn{1}{...}\begingroup...\endgroup` works, can you?

Comment: I thought that begingroup stand for {. I will work on your answer later. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer, as it is very unclear what you're about.

The syntax

```
\multicolumn{1}{@{c@{}}}\begingroup...\endgroup
```

is completely wrong. You *can't* delimit standard arguments with `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

What you can do is, maybe, adding

```
\protected\def\mymulti\begingroup#1\endgroup{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}%
}
```

and use `\mymulti\begingroup...\endgroup` in your code.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this command, because the problem is the same. My foreach loop cut the command in two parts : at each turn first close the previous multicolumn then & sign and finally opening of the next multicolumn.

Comment: @Tarass That is not possible, macro arguments cannot be split at the execution level.

Comment: @Tarass The problem is that `\def` already starts a cell.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek it can be done with lualatex, see my edit (not the spliting, but the entire command line).

Comment: @egreg you speak about the parasite verticales lines ?